# Lightswitch RIA Service Include related domain service Entity in zero or one to many case

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, ria

I have set up my DomainService and here is the data structure(one **CombinedStadium** may have many **CombindeEcoStatus**)

```
public class CombinedStadium
{
    [Key]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [Include]
    [Association("Stadium_EcoStatus", "SiteId", "StadiumId")]
    public IQueryable<CombindeEcoStatus> EcoStatus { get; set; }
}

public class CombindeEcoStatus
{
    private CombinedStadium _combinedStadium;
    [Key]
    public int EcoId { get; set; }
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public int StadiumId { get; set; }
    [Include]
    [Association("Stadium_EcoStatus", "StadiumId", "SiteId", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public virtual CombinedStadium Stadium
    {
        get { return this._combinedStadium; }
        set
        {
            this._combinedStadium = value;
            if (value == null)
            {
                this.StadiumId = value.SiteId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the query is

```
    [Query(IsDefault = true)]
    public IQueryable<CombinedStadium> GetAllStadiums()
    {
        var stadiumsQuery = from stadium in this.Context.StadiumSet
                            select new
                            {
                                SiteId = stadium.Id
                            };

        return stadiumsQuery;
    }
```

When I consume this RIA service in my lightswitch app as datasource, I want to query the stadium by SiteId(stadium's ID) and return its related CombindeEcoStatus data.How can I do this? Thanks a lot !!!(By the way,why cant I find the **StadiumId** property in my generated Lightswitch data table?Since it is the FK in the "**Stadium_EcoStatus**" Association?)

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact problem here and seem to remember running into difficulty myself in this area once. However, I'm sure if you'll find the answer anywhere you'll find on Michael Washington's excellent website [which you can find here.](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/tagid/21/Default.aspx) That link takes you specifically to his Lightswitch & WCF RIA section. Hope that helps you in the right direction.

Comment: eh, my problem is when I query the stadium , I can only get **CombinedStadium** Items ,But I want to get the related **CombindeEcoStatus** Items at the same time. The **include** method can not be used in domain service Entities?